# Why does the line item rate change when updating the vendor on bill in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript1.0

I am attempting to update the vendor (`entity`) on a vendor bill from one value to another using SuiteScript 1.0. The value updates successfully but the rate on the bill line item changes unexpectedly as well. This also happens when updating via the UI.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

All Entities (Vendors, Customers, etc) can have their own custom Price Levels and Discounts. Check the Vendor record for this information.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Is there any way to prevent this behavior? We're creating vendor bills from purchase orders using `nlapiTransformRecord` and so we want to preserve the price from the PO.